# JavaFX changing Pane within VBox

Tags: javafx

I have a mainView.fxml which includes 3 separate fxml files. My mainView is designed like that (VBox) and will be loaded by the start method.

```
+------------------------+
+ menu (menu.fxml)       +
+------------------------+
+ toolbar (toolbar.fxml) +
+------------------------+
+                        +
+ dashboardXYZ           +
+ (dashboarXYZ.fxml)     +
+------------------------+
```

By clicking an icon of the toolbar the contentZYZ shall be updated with the content of different fxml files. Pretty basic stuff.

My mainView.fxml

```
<VBox fx:id="mainView" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.test.controller.MainController">
<children>
    <fx:include fx:id="menu" source="menu.fxml" />
    <fx:include fx:id="menuToolbar" source="menuToolbar.fxml" />
    <fx:include fx:id="contentXYZ" source="contentXYZ.fxml" />
</children>
```

mainController

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane dashboardHome;
@FXML
private VBox mainView;


public void loadContent() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/test/view/courseView.fxml"));
    AnchorPane newPane = fxmlLoader.load();

    System.out.println(mainView.getChildren()); // is null!!

    // Set the loaded FXML file as the content of our main right-side pane
    //mainView.getChildren().set(2, newPane);

}
```

Results in a

```
NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getChildren()" because "this.mainView" is null
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are in one controller instance, but the loader is tied with a different controller instance. I think you might have created your MainContrller instance manually elsewhere and calling loadContent().

If you want to keep the loadContent() method in MainController , you can try one of the below two approaches.

**Approach #1:**  Accessing the nodes from FXMLLoader controller

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane dashboardHome;
@FXML
private VBox mainView;

public void loadContent() throws IOException{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/test/view/courseView.fxml"));
    AnchorPane newPane = fxmlLoader.load();
    MainController controller = (MainController) fxmlLoader.getController();

    System.out.println(controller.mainView.getChildren()); 
}
```

**Approach #2:**  Setting the current controller instance as the controller to the loader.

For this you need to first remove the controller declaration in the fxml file. Because we set the controller manually to the loader.

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane dashboardHome;
@FXML
private VBox mainView;

public void loadContent() throws IOException{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/test/view/courseView.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    AnchorPane newPane = fxmlLoader.load();
    
    System.out.println(mainView.getChildren()); 
}
```